# how to calculate geometric values in C#

Tags: c#-3.0

i want design a dll for geometric points
i have x value and y value from that i have to enter more x value and y value and two x points and two y points means.i have to find the distance...this is one dll then second class library we have to get the points from first class library and calculate slope angel

Answer (score 0):

You can simple calc it from Pythagoras.

Comment: i"m new for c# can u provide example for creating two or more classes in class library and access one to another claa